# banner advertising mysql-query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, ads, banner, multiple-tables

My problem is described further under the table structure.

This is my tables for my advertising banner system:

### banner

id (unique key)

title

bannersrc

maxhits

maxklik

activefrom

activeuntil

dato

### bannerhits (number of shows)

id (unique key)

ip

bannerid (index) (referring to banner.id)

dato

### bannerklik (number of clicks)

id (unique key)

ip

bannerid (index) (referring to banner.id)

dato

### question

What I want is to make an query that selects a banner from the table 'banner' WHERE:

(b.usertype = $usertype OR b.usertype = '0')

AND

(
activefrom <= now
activeuntil >= now

OR

maxklik > number of rows in 'bannerklik' where bannerklik.bannerid = banner.id

OR

maxhits > number of rows in 'bannerhits' where bannerhits.bannerid = banner.id
)

Can you create a query for me, because I really don't get how to make that :)

Comment: there is no usertype field on any table ...

Answer (score 0):

i think the following should work .. (assuming you have a usertype field in the banner table)

```
SELECT
     b.id, b.title, b.bannersrc
FROM
     banner b 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN bannerhits bh ON b.id = bh.bannerid
     LEFT OUTER JOIN bannerklik bk ON b.id = bk.bannerid 
WHERE
     (b.usertype = '0' OR b.usertype = $usertype)
     AND 
     (b.activefrom <= curdate() AND b.activeuntil >= curdate())
GROUP BY 
     b.id, b.title, b.bannersrc, b.maxklik, b.maxhits
HAVING
     ( 
      b.maxklik > count( DISTINCT(bk.id) )
      OR
      b.maxhits > count( DISTINCT(bh.id) )
     )
```

**[EDIT 1]**

ok lets revise the conditions here..

You want the following conditions to be true at the same time in order to display an ad

1. b.usertype be '0' or some value you pass in the $usertype variable
2. any one of the following rules

   1. b.activefrom <= curdate() AND b.activeuntil >= curdate()
   2. b.maxklik > count( DISTINCT(bk.id)
   3. b.maxhits > count( DISTINCT(bh.id)

am i correct ?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It seems to work - well at least no mysql-error :P

Comment: it will select banners that have usertype 0 or the one you provide, whose active dates include today, and whose maxklik or maxhits are not maxed out

Comment: Well, it doesn't exactly do what I want :P
the banners to be selected is:
the ones that has 
maxklik > count(DISTINCT(bk.id))
OR
maxhits > count(DISTINCT(bh.id) )
OR
b.activefrom <= curdate() AND b.activeuntil >= curdate()

the b.usertype = '0' OR b.usertype = $usertype is only so the advertisers can have their ad show to a special type of users - if you're usertype 1 you only get showed WHERE usertype = 0 or 1, if it is to usertype = 0 or 2 and so on.

Comment: ok .. we need to establish the correct grouping of conditions.. i will edit my answer (to have formatting)